# Spring Transaction Management with legacy JDBC

Tags: spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I am trying to inject Spring Transaction Management on to legacy JDBC code.But it fails in transaction management.

My Spring.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

```
<bean id="dbcpDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@sbsvmlx101.suntecsbs.com:1521:orcl11g" />
    <property name="username" value="XLRT2_TEST_MAIN" />
    <property name="password" value="XLRT2_TEST_MAIN" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

and annotated my service method with @Transactional.

```
@Transactional  
public void createEmp(Employee employee, DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager)throws Exception {  
    generaldao.createEmployee(employee,dataSourceTransactionManager);  
}
```

I am trying to insert data into two different tables.First one got successfully inserted,and knowingly i made an error in second insertion ,expecting that the both insertions won't happen. 
But surprisingly ,the first insertion got committed, and second has shown oracle error.

DAO

```
con = DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(dataSource);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        insert = con.prepareStatement
                    ("insert into emp500 values(?,?,?)");
         insert.setInt(1, 1);
         insert.setString(2, "test");
         insert.setString(3, "data");
         insert.execute();

         insertdept = con.prepareStatement
                        ("insert into department values(?,?)");
         insertdept.setInt(1, 2);
         insertdept.setString(2, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"); //too large value for the column
         insertdept.execute();
```

Please advice.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How does the `createEmpl` method is invoked? How did you retrieve the instance of the service?

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll  EmployeeMgr employeeMgr = tx.getBean("employeeMgr",EmployeeMgr.class); employeeMgr.createEmp(emp );

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Can you enable debug log for `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource` and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneNicoll for your time. But I tried logging using commnos-logging1.1.1.jar.But still I am not getting any other info other tahn which I logged. My logger.properites looks like below         log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=trace, stdout

log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=DEBUG

Comment: It worked when I throwed DataAccessException.    My Catch block Code     SQLExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator = new SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator(dataSource);
     
throw exceptionTranslator.translate("PreparedStatementCallback", "", e.getSqlEx());